mlkit:text-recognition-chinese Not working properly
Package com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-chinese:16.0.0 into apk through bundling and packaging. When running the AndroidTest case, an exception occurs and the focus cannot be moved. After uninstalling the apk, the focus can move normally.
run a AndroidTest can reproduce :

create a bitmap by picture,convert bitmap into com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage image
TextRecognizer recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(new ChineseTextRecognizerOptions.Builder().build());
recognizer.process(image)
See error in log or /data/tombstone:

Build fingerprint: 'xxxx:userdebug/test-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 5975, tid: 6063, name: Thread-2 >>> com.xxxx.xxxx <<<
signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 0x9620b5b4
r0 945a33d0 r1 00000008 r2 00000100 r3 945a30d8
r4 945c2478 r5 00000020 r6 945c24f8 r7 00000008
r8 945c24b8 r9 94d64080 r10 945a32d0 r11 945c2438
ip 945a31d0 sp 94201850 lr 961cb48f pc 9620b5b4
backtrace:
#00 pc 003c95b4 /data/app/com.xxxx.xxxx-8ktOafHLs7wWtOh_j94VPQ==/lib/arm/libmlkit_google_ocr_pipeline.so
Expected behavior:
The test case passed and the text was successfully recognized
SDK Info:
com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-chinese:16.0.0
Smartphone:
Device/Simulator OS:
Android 9.0 [ro.build.version.sdk]: [28]
Development Environment:
(For Android issue feel free to skip this section)
IDE Eversion:
Android Studio 4.1.3
Laptop/Desktop:
windows 10 professional version
tryed:clean project and rebuild
expecting:The test case passed and the text was successfully recognized
